# How retrieve Default Org Values from Custom Settings to Visual Studio?

Tags: customsetting, package, visualstudiocode, aws, retrieve

We want to change our 'Default Org Values' in our repo, but we don't find the option in Visual Studio. We are using Visual to upload the code to AWS and need to change this.
We tried to include the Custom Setting in the package.xml with the Default Org Values correctly but nothing happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command :

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:<Custom Setting API Name>
```

- You can also modify your package.xml from your manifest folder to include the
  below code

  [image]

Comment: Including that code we can import the CustomSetting, but the Default Org Value doesn't change.